# Magento Enterprise - Bundled Items Quote Price is $0.00

Tags: magento-1.13

We are trying to export an order detail (via the SOAP api) that includes a bundled product and we need the price each individual item in the bundle was sold for. The problem is, the prices of the individual items are all $0.00 (price and base_price). I have tracked it back to the quote item is stored in the database as 0.00.

In other Magento systems I can see the price of each individual item. On these systems the database saves the price in the price and base_price columns.

Any ideas on where to look where the data is being zeroed out?

Magento ver. 1.13.0.2

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a configuration issue. When the bundle price is fixed then the prices are not available at the item level.